# How to get notifications on questions not asked by me on Stack Overflow mobile app?

Tags: discussion, notifications

I have installed the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow mobile apps on my phone.

Currently, I am only able to get notifications from questions asked by myself. What if I want to get phone notifications for good questions that are not asked by me?

Comment: That's not possible at all, with either stock version of the site or mobile apps, AFAIK. All you can do is star another's question -- then you'll get notifications of new answers to it only.